# External SSO and Web Application running on TOMCAT 6.0

Tags: single-sign-on

New to JAVA. I developed Web application(JSP) successfully delpoyed on TOMCAT 6.0. Now the client want to use external SSO to authenticate users. As of now when the users are authenticated the website is displayed with Login Page where the user has to login again.

I am using the Login.jsp to bring the user roles from the SQLDB for Website.

What I want to accomplish now is when User is authenticated login.jsp should retrieve the credentials from the SSO and display the website thus accomplishing the purpose of Single sign on process.

I read a lot from this forum and other websites but kinda lost in the process.

Any help would be appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

We developed a Tomcat extension (valve) which does just that. Basically you use standard J2EE security (role-ref etc) in your app and our Tomcat valve then acts as a bridge between Tomcat and our SSO platform. You can find out more at [www.cloudseal.com](http://www.cloudseal.com/java-downloads/tomcat-plugin/)

Of course you may not want to use our SSO platform :-( but you can still use our Tomcat valve and modify it to fit your needs. It's released under an Apache 2 license and you can grab the source from [Github](https://github.com/cloudseal/tomcat-valve)